# Retrieving the right position of a scaled UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, position, scale

I'm having trouble retrieving the current position of a view, absolutely in the iPhone screen, when the view is scaled.
Here is a minimal example of what I've done.

I have a single elliptical view on screen. When I tap, it grows and start to shiver to show that it is selected. Then I can drag the view all over the screen.

Here is the code:

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // The View
    let toDrag = MyView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 40))
    toDrag.center = CGPoint(x:100, y:100)
    // The gesture recognizer
    let panGestRec = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.panView(sender:)))
    toDrag.addGestureRecognizer(panGestRec)

    self.view.addSubview(toDrag)
}

func panView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let senderView = sender.view else { return }

    if sender.state == .recognized { print("Pan Recognized", terminator:"")}
    if sender.state == .began { print("Pan began", terminator: "") }
    if sender.state == .changed { print("Pan changed", terminator: "") }
    if sender.state == .ended { print("Pan ended", terminator: "") }

    let point = senderView.convert(senderView.center, to: nil)

    print (" point \(point)")
    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    senderView.center = CGPoint(x: senderView.center.x + translation.x, y: senderView.center.y + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
}
```

**MyView**

```
import UIKit

class MyView: UIView {

var isAnimated: Bool = false

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame) // calls designated initializer
    self.isOpaque = false
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.isOpaque = false
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    isAnimated = true
    rotate1()
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    isAnimated = false
    endRotation()
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    isAnimated = false
    endRotation()
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return}
    context.addEllipse(in: rect)
    context.setLineWidth(1.0)
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
    context.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
}

func rotate1() {
    guard isAnimated else { return }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay:0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle:.pi/16).scaledBy(x: 1.5, y: 1.5)
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.rotate2()
    })
}

func rotate2() {
    guard isAnimated else { return }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay:0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle:.pi/(-16)).scaledBy(x: 1.5, y: 1.5)
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.rotate1()
    })

}
func endRotation () {
    // End existing animation
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay:0.0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle:0 ).scaledBy(x: 1, y: 1)
    }, completion: nil)
}
}
```

With this version, here are some displays of the position

```
Pan began point (233.749182687299, 195.746572421573)
Pan changed point (175.265022520054, 181.332358181369)
Pan changed point (177.265022520054, 184.332358181369)
Pan changed point (177.265022520054, 184.332358181369)
Pan changed point (178.265022520054, 185.332358181369)
Pan changed point (179.265022520054, 186.332358181369)
Pan changed point (180.265022520054, 187.332358181369)
Pan changed point (180.265022520054, 188.332358181369)
Pan changed point (181.265022520054, 188.332358181369)
Pan RecognizedPan ended point (181.265022520054, 189.332358181369)
```

You can see that the first position (began point) isn't correct: the view was animated at that moment. The other positions are OK, when dragging, the view don't animate.

If I comment the code in rotate1 and rotate2, all the positions are correct, so I assume that the sizing and eventually the rotation of the view are interfering in the result. My question is: how can I retrieve the correct position of the view, when it is scaled? Obviously, the line

> senderView.convert(senderView.center, to: nil)

didn't make what I thought : converting the coordinate to the fixed size screen coordinates?

Comment: When you change a view's transform it's frame becomes invalid, but the center is still supposed to be correct.  I believe that if you translate the view then the center-point will also be translated, but I'm not positive of that. It's a bit hard to follow the data you're showing and tell what's happening however.

Comment: I explain my goals: In fact, the view is a pawn, and the screen is a board. So I wanted to know where the pawn begins moving, and where it ends. The animation is just for visually checking that the good pawn is selected. The sources are complete: you can create a new projet, replace viewcontroller source, add MyView file and it should work like on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I had another problem with view convert ([Retrieve the right position of a subView with auto-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314549/retrieve-the-right-position-of-a-subview-with-auto-layout))
and my problem was the same, so the solution is here...

I didn't use the method correctly. If I change using [beninho85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2843196/beninho85/)'s solution (and even more cleaner [cosyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1294391/cosyn)'s method to use just one view), it works! I can have the right coordinates even if the view is animated.

I just had to replace, in  ViewController :

> let point = senderView.convert(senderView.center, to: nil)

with

> let point = senderView.convert(CGPoint(x:senderView.bounds.midX, y:senderView.bounds.midY), to: nil)

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing the animation from View animation to Core Animation (layer), and the result was the same.

So I tried to imagine a formula, with size, bounds and frame values, that could result in the correct position, but I did not succeed...

The only think that worked, was to stop immediately the animation with a transform, just before trying to retrieve the center, like that in panView

```
func panView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let senderView = sender.view else { return }

    // Stop the transformation now!
    senderView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle:0 ).scaledBy(x: 1, y: 1)

    if sender.state == .recognized { print("Pan Recognized", terminator:"")}
    ...
```

It isn't the solution I wanted, but I'll go with this for now...